# how do I get necessary values of header of ID3v2?

Tags: c, mp3, id3v2

I'm trying to read header of ID3V2 of mp3 files. I can get/print ID3 and want to print out "version" and "subversion" which is type char, but I can't get what i need.

here is code:

```
    }
    .....
    fseek(file,0,SEEK_SET); 
    fread(&tag.TAG, 1, sizeof(tag),file); // tag is structure with elements of header

    if(strncmp(tag.TAG,"ID3", 3) == 0)
    {
        fread(&tag.version,1, sizeof(tag),file);
        fread(&tag.subversion,1, sizeof(tag),file);

    printf("ID3v2.%s.%s", tag.version, tag.subversion);
   }
}
```

A.

Comment: why do you remove the formatting?

Comment: Why are you reading `sizeof(tag)` bytes? the fread call should probably look like `fread(&member, sizeof member, 1, file)`. **And test the return value of `fread()`!**

Comment: Stop editing answers to reply to them; edit or leave a comment on your own question instead (and if/when you hit 50 rep you can leave comments on the answers as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read only once the header. i.e. if you have

```
struct id3v2hdr {
    char TAG[3];
    unsigned char version;
    unsigned char subversion;
    ...
}
```

Your code would be:

```
fseek(file,0,SEEK_SET); 
fread(&tag.TAG, 1, sizeof(tag),file); // tag is structure with elements of header

if(strncmp(tag.TAG,"ID3", 3) == 0)
{
    printf("ID3v2.%hhd.%hhd", tag.version, tag.subversion);
}
```

Note that `version` and `subversion` are byte-sized integers, not printable characters, so you should use `%hhu` (`%hhd` if they are signed) as its format specification.

Also, the pointer to the first element of a struct, and the pointer to a struct compare equal, so changing your `fread` line to:

```
fread(&tag, 1, sizeof(tag),file); // tag is structure with elements of header
```

is unnecessary (tough it would show the intent much more clearly).

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading enough bytes? You are passing the address of tag.TAG, but supplying sizeof(tag) and not sizeof(tag.TAG).

Answer (score 0):

That would be `%c` for printing a char and not `%s` (used for printing null-terminated `char*`):

```
printf("ID3v2.%c.%c", tag.version, tag.subversion);
```

Use `%d` if you want to see the byte as a number.

Comment: actually, `%hhd`, for a `char` treated as an integer.